# get Tooltip text/innerHTML on click

Tags: highcharts

can anybody help in how to get tooltip text/innerHTML on click of highchart.
by using following example i am able to get name of chart area.
but unable to get chart area tooltip.

demo link is [`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/TGw5M/6/)

Answer (score 4):

You can get it like this:

```
console.log($('.highcharts-tooltip tspan').text());
```

or

```
alert($('.highcharts-tooltip tspan').text());
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/TGw5M/7/